# Adding oval shape to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

Here's my simple code. I don't really know how to add a drawn oval to a `JPanel`. I did some paintings before, but I have never used the constructor so I don't have an idea.

```
public class Buffer extends JPanel{
    public JFrame frame;
    public JPanel panel;

    public Buffer(){
        frame=new JFrame();
        panel=new JPanel();

        panel.setSize(500,500);
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);

        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.fillOval(20,20,20,20);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Buffer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic structure of your code is wrong. The Buffer class should not be creating a frame. The Buffer class should just be used for painting. The code should be something like:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Buffer oval = new Buffer();
    oval.setBackground(Color.RED);

    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.add( oval );
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Make sure you invoke super.paintComponent() (without the "s"). You should also be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method to set the size of your custom component. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and a better example.