# More effective KeyListener implementation

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I have some experiences with painting in Java. Basically I know how to add key listeners to a frame but I'd like to know if there's any other way how to add all those methods than just writing them after or before main method. This approach kind of makes my code badly readable.

```
public class test extends JPanel {
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel panel;
    public static int x;
    public static int y;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);      
        g.fillOval(x,y,20,20);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test x=new test();

        x.setBackground(Color.white);

        frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.add(x);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you not read the `Custom Painting` tutorial as was suggested in your last posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753492/adding-oval-shape-to-jpanel. This is NOT the way to structure a class. You should not be using static variables. You have not implemented the getPreferredSize() method. `frame` and `panel` are not variables that should be defined in your class. `text` is not a proper class name. Why ask questions when you don't listen to the advice??? Finally DON'T use KeyListener. There are better API's to use to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Adapters reduces a lot of code:

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
 @Override
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
// do what ever you want
}
});
```

In the above example you can also override  `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` methods, but this will be valid only for the *frame*.
If you have a time, take a look to [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: +1 for, but Top-Level Container by default never interact with KeyEvents from KeyListener